# Eclipse doesn't recognize lua files after installing the lua plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lua

I downloaded Eclipse Classic off of the Eclipse website then the [Lua Eclipse IDE plugin](http://luaforge.net/projects/lua-eclipse-ide/). I followed the install instructions but Eclipse doesn't seem to recognize or be able to understand lua files. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your file types aren't associated.  Click on Window/Preferences and select General/Editors/File Associations.

Comment: The type associations are there, but when i open up a lua file the editor says ERROR

Comment: I'm trying LuaEclipse now maybe that will help.

Comment: @RCIX: I drag and dropped a random file into Eclipse, and I have this ERROR message. Looks like files must be in a project to be correctly handled.

Answer (score 0):

Add more information

- Which installation guide did you follow? ([Lua Eclipse Installation](http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/manual.html#installation)?)
- Which OS (version)?
- Which java version? (Which [implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines))
- Which eclipse version?

Comment: 1. The installation that came with the download 2. W7 RTM 3. Build 1.6.0_16-b01 (from Sun) 4. Whatever the latest is

Answer (score 0):

I love these kind of questions because they provide an opportunity to do a test I postponed until now...

So I downloaded the plugin package, and followed the instructions: closed Eclipse, put two jar files in the plugin folder, put the open-ldb.exe elsewhere, restarted Eclipse.
I created a generic project, added a generic file linked to an existing Lua file. When I opened the file, it was automatically identified as such, with a moon icon and correct syntax highlighting.
Using Eclipse 3.5.1 on Windows XP, BTW.

Now, I have an issue, the debugger won't start for me, I get a

> Unable to connect to PDA VM
>   Connection refused: connect

error, not sure why (path to exe file is correct, I have another error when it is wrong).

But at least I have the Lua files recognized without problem.
I think you might want to check that in Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations, *.lua is defined and associated to the Lua editor.

Comment: It is, i'm trying LuaEclipse now and scratching my head over how to get the lua interpreter connected.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of opening a File you have to do the following:

Open a new LUA project.
Then import using 'File System' all files (resources and LUA files) into the project.

Now you can see and edit the LUA files. Don't know why it doesn't work by simply opening a LUA file directly.