# How do I easily open a lua file on MacOS?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I installed the Corona SDK on MacOS. Now I'm trying to open a .lua file. My most preferable way I've found to do it so far is to right-click and then Open With->Other... and select Text Wrangler. I installed the lua plug-in for Eclipse but Eclipse says it cannot open files of this type (though it works from inside a project). How can I quickly open a file for editing, for example type command+O and have it show up in Eclipse.

Comment: You're asking how to associate a file extension with an application? Suggest you try: http://apple.stackexchange.com/ Or perhaps see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635881/eclipse-doesnt-recognize-lua-files-after-installing-the-lua-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the file. Type Cmd+i. In the "Open with" section, choose the program you'd like to use to open it in the drop down menu.